# Are there any Bible that comes with explanations of each verses?

Tags: bible

I'm looking for a NLT Bible which would have explanations of each verse? I would like to do a deeper study and don't want to end up misinterpreting some of those verses. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, they're called Study Bibles. There are usually several for each translation. But they don't guarantee the "correct" interpretation, and if you rely on them instead of developing greater reading and exegesis skills yourself, then you can be sure you will misunderstand the scriptures many times.

Comment: Here is a study Bible based on the NLT translation: http://www.nltstudybible.com/ . There is a sample available (book of Matthew) from the site. I would suggest also reading other Bible versions and other study Bibles, many of which are available online or as installable programs.

Comment: @disciple, Thanks. I went through the sample pages of the NLT  Bible that you suggested me. It's good but i think i like their illustrated study edition more ... Any idea why the English Old Testament is divided into 4 parts in the NLT, while in the NASB study bible of John F. MacArthur, it has been divided into 5 parts?

Comment: Five divisions is most common. I couldn't find a good reference, so this site could use a question about Bible divisions. I would guess the NLT treated the major prophets and the minor prophets as one division.

Comment: Following from curiousdanni's comment, I'd suggest (a) check at least two separate sources for study notes or commentaries. They may not disagree but very often they will have different perspectives as to what they consider significant. (b) take some time to learn the basic skills of reading and interpreting on your own.  (c) pray, Pray, PRAY as you read!  The Holy Spirit is the one who ultimately gives us reliable insight and understanding of the Bible:  (John 14:26)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explanations of the Bible are called *commentaries*, and there are [lots of them available](https://www.blueletterbible.org/commentaries/index.cfm). Some commentaries are focused on a specific book or section of the Bible, and some comprehensive commentaries attempt to cover the whole Bible.

Of course, these commentaries are written by people, and as such the explanations are from the theological viewpoint of whoever wrote it. You can select commentaries based on your preferred denomination, or you can read multiple commentaries and learn multiple views on the scripture.

*Study Bibles* are Bibles with commentary built-in. Usually these include notes at the bottom of each page with commentary on whatever verses are on that page. A study Bible can be very useful for getting a quick explanation of a verse that is giving you trouble. But again, this commentary is written by a person, so it is not infallible and contains a denominational bias, so keep that in mind as you read, and consult other commentaries as part of your study.